# How should I redirect the second page in Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

My application has 3 JSP pages: one is `login.jsp`, and the others are `loginSuccess.jsp` and `loginFail.jsp`. If the username and the password in the login form are correct then it goes to the loginSuccess page but when the username and password are not correct, it doesn't go to the loginFail page.

What do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: First of all you probably need to post code or offer more information for us to help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/)

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security has properties in the config xml.  Something like this should do the trick!

```
    default-target-url="loginSuccess.jsp" 
    authentication-failure-url="/loginFail.jsp"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use Spring Security, I think you can use spring mvc RedirectView to redirect the request to differenct pages.

```
    if (success) {
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("loginSuccess.jsp"));
    } else {
        return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("loginFail.jsp"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [AbstractWizardFormController](http://docs.huihoo.com/javadoc/spring/2.5/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/AbstractWizardFormController.html) if Spring Security is an overkill.